# Changing label text after adding it to self?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I'm trying to change the text for a `SKLabelNode` node after it's added to self.

This is how I create it on initialization:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

        // Add label
        SKLabelNode *timeLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"timeLabel"];
        timeLabel.text = @"5";
        timeLabel.fontSize = 100;
        timeLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);
        [self addChild:timeLabel];

    }
    return self;
}
```

How can I change its text on `touchesBegan`?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Change label text?
}
```

Comment: first of all you need a global reference for the `timeLabel` (currently you have a local one only), then you can change the text via the `–setText:` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add:

```
@property (nonatomic) SKLabelNode *timeLabel;
```

intWithSize:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];

    // Add label
    self.timeLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"timeLabel"];
    self.timeLabel.text = @"5";
    self.timeLabel.fontSize = 100;
    self.timeLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100);
    [self addChild:self.timeLabel];

}
return self;
}
```

change text:

```
self.timeLabel.text = @"changeText";
```